# Is it possible to shoot right through a tank?

Tags: world-of-tanks

So, I have been wondering: If I load an AP, APCR or HEAT(not sure how HEAT exactly works), can I damage 2 vehicles at once with a single non-HE shell? Of couse, I mean HP damage, not critical damage.

That means the shell must shoot right through a tank. Is this possible?

Comment: Since that might pop up in search; not what you're asking in the question body but definitely matches the title: you can shoot right through a tank and not damage it at all. It's a very old, rather rare but definitely still present bug called 'ghost shell', your shell passing through a tank without colliding with it at all.

Comment: The first clip in [this compilation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlmtBvls3JY) shows a blatant occurrence of this bug, with KV-2's HE shell going right across an enemy IS without dealing any damage - and killing an ally KV-1S behind. At 0:24 you can observe the shell path in slow motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, after update 9.3, in theory this is possible however highly unlikely.

After hitting a tank your shell will continue travelling for 10 times its caliber. For example a 100mm shell will travel for 1 meter after impact.

Also, after a shell penetrates, it will lose penetration value equal to the amount of armor penetrated. For example, a shell with 200mm of penetration will have 100mm of penetration left after penetrating.

Imagine firing a 150mm caliber shell with 200mm penetration at a tank with 80mm of armor. In this case it would have to enter the tank, exit the tank, leaving it with 40mm of penetration and striking the 2nd verhicle all within a distance of 1.5 meters after the initial impact.

Comment: Does this also work with HEAT shells? Or do they just get stuck in the 1st tank?

Comment: Yeah same goes for HEAT (and HESH), only exception is HE

Comment: @user3.14159265359 Super cool.

Comment: Penning even one armor layer is a challenge. In this case you need to pen three: first tank twice, then second tank once. Never mind most tanks are wider than 2 meters, so the shell to hit the other one would likely need to clip a corner of the first tank... and not get swallowed by tracks and not get sunken by angled armor. I guess this might be possible for some paper TDs like M56 Scorpion (a whole 1mm of armor everywhere!) but the geometry involved is still silly.

Comment: I'm curious if you hit the gun perpendicular if that would actually count as 2 pens. We know in reality it would be, just not sure if the tanks are modeled that way.  Or if there are other ways to clip a tank with a single pen.

Comment: Are you sure HEAT and HESH do it the same way? HEAT= on hit on a hard surface, a small burst of molten copper is shoot through the metal | HESH= HE Squash Head = HE with a Metal Plate in front of the Bullet